# Problem with My Class Variables Array is not working as intended - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, oop

To give some context. So for this project I have an array of my class variables, the cd1. That is the variable for the AudioCD and it is an array because if the user wants to enter more CD in to the array.

The problem I am getting is that when I enter more then one cd into the class array, at around the part where I add the string or artist is where I get the issue. When I go to print the class variables specific index which should be seperate, mostly everything except the artist array for the shows the last entered lines for some weird reason. I am trying to figure out why it is doing this.

PS. Sorry is my explanation is not the best.

As you see in the image. The out put should be when I input 1 for choice and 1 for the CD, the array should use the array for index 0, but it is using the array from the last inputted CD. The output should be:

man1
man2
man3

but it is:

man4
man5
man6

```cs
    class AudioCD
    {
        // Private Variables for CDclass 
        public string cdTitle { get; private set; }
        private string[] artists = new string[4];
        public int releaseYear { get; private set; }
        public string genre { get; private set; }
        public float condition { get; private set; }

        // Constructor for the CDclass - initializes all variables used in the CDclass
        public AudioCD()
        {
            cdTitle = "";
            artists = new string[] {"","","",""};
            releaseYear = 1980;
            genre = "";
            condition = 0.0f;
        }

        // Overload Constructor for the CDclass - initializes all the variables to user input variables
        public AudioCD(string cdt, string[] art, int reY, string gen, float con)
        {
            
            cdTitle = cdt;

            if (artists.Length < art.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Array size is bigger then 4 for the Artist so the first 4 names will be used!");
            }
            artists = art;

            if (reY < 1980)
            {
                releaseYear = 1980;
            }
            else
            {
                releaseYear = reY;
            }
            genre = gen;
            if (con < 0.0f || con > 5.0f)
            {
                condition = 0.0f;
            }
            else
            {
                condition = con;
            }
        }

        public void printAudioCD()
        {
            Console.Write(cdTitle + ", " + releaseYear + "\n" );
            for (int i = 0; i < artists.Length; i++)
            {
                if (artists[i] != "" )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Artist (#" + (i + 1) + "): " + artists[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Genre: " + genre);
            Console.WriteLine("Condition: " + condition);

        }

    }
```

and `Program` class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // variables
        string uI, cdtitle, genre;
        int size = 0, releaseYear, choice, arrInd;
        string[] artistArray = new string[4] {"", "", "", "" };
        float condition;

        //
        AudioCD remote = new AudioCD();

        Console.Write("How many CDs do you have lying around your car? ");
        uI = Console.ReadLine();
        size = Convert.ToInt32(uI);

        AudioCD[] cd1 = new AudioCD[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CD #" + (i + 1));
            Console.Write("*Enter Title: ");
            uI = Console.ReadLine();
            cdtitle = uI;

            Console.WriteLine("*Enter Artists (type -1 when finished):");
             int j = 0;
            do
            {
                uI = Console.ReadLine();
                if (uI != "-1")
                    artistArray[j] = uI;
                j++;

                // Resize the array by One Element
                if (j >= 4 && uI != "-1")
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref artistArray, artistArray.Length + 1);
                    artistArray[j] = "";
                }

            } while (uI != "-1" );

            Console.Write("*Enter Genre: ");
            uI = Console.ReadLine();
            genre = uI;

            Console.Write("*Enter Release Year: ");
            uI = Console.ReadLine();
            releaseYear = Convert.ToInt32(uI);

            Console.Write("*Enter Condition: ");
            uI = Console.ReadLine();
            condition = float.Parse(uI);

            Console.Write("\n");

            // switch to select which class of cd to put information in
            cd1[i] = new AudioCD(cdtitle, artistArray, releaseYear, genre, condition);
            

        }

        bool isPlaying = true;

        while(isPlaying)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("[Main Menu]");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Album Info");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Find a CD");
            Console.WriteLine("3) Find an artist");
            Console.WriteLine("4) Log off");
            Console.Write("Choice: ");
            uI = Console.ReadLine();
            choice = Convert.ToInt32(uI);

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        Console.Write("\nWhich CD do you want? ");
                        uI = Console.ReadLine();
                        arrInd = Convert.ToInt32(uI);

                        if (arrInd >= 1 || arrInd <= size)
                        {
                            Console.Write(arrInd + ". ");
                            cd1[(arrInd - 1)].printAudioCD();
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    {
                        isPlaying = false;
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**
As you see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV9ee.png). The out put should be when I input 1 for choice and 1 for the CD, the array should use the array for index 0, but it is using the array from the last inputted CD. The output should be man1,man2, and man3, but it is man4, man5, and man6.

Comment: You're reusing the same `artistArray` for each iteration, unless you happen to need to resize it. Each CD needs a separate array. (I'd also suggest using `List<T>` instead of arrays, so you don't need to worry about resizing etc.)

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense now but I'm not sure how to implement that. I was under the impression that each that the way I had it should have its own thing because artistArray is just a temp array being used to send that array as a parameter for when a new class is made. Do i need to reset the array before sending it to the class. 
I will look into using list but I have never used them before.

Comment: No, you need to create a *new* array. I suspect you need to understand the difference between reference types (including arrays) and value types. See https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. I kinda understand why ot is not working and I need ti research it more later. Is there a better way of doing what I am doing. The class has to have those elements in it and the only reason why I made the class variable is because if the user wants to enter more cd, they can do so.

Comment: Yes, it would be better to use a `List<string>`... and I'd also extract out the "ask a user for CD details" as a separate method that you call from Main... that's likely to simplify things a lot. Any more detail than that is really out of the scope of a stack overflow question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same array in your `Main()` for each iteration and this is the reason why you got the artists from the last inputted CD. I mean this code snippet:

```
string[] artistArray = new string[4] {"", "", "", "" };
```

Here we can use `List<T>` to avoid writing code of resizing of an array and we can use [Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.clear?view=net-6.0) method to avoid storing artists from the previous CD.

The whole code would look like this. I've refactored your code a little bit by using [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0):

The class `AudioCD`:

```
public class AudioCD
{
    // Private Variables for CDclass 
    public string cdTitle { get; private set; }

    private List<string> artists = new List<string>();
    public int releaseYear { get; private set; }
    public string genre { get; private set; }
    public float condition { get; private set; }

    // Constructor for the CDclass - initializes all variables used in the CDclass
    public AudioCD()
    {
        cdTitle = "";
        releaseYear = 1980;
        genre = "";
        condition = 0.0f;
    }

    // Overload Constructor for the CDclass - initializes all the variables to user input variables
    public AudioCD(string cdt, List<string> art, int reY, string gen, float con)
    {

        cdTitle = cdt;

        artists.AddRange(art);

        if (reY < 1980)
        {
            releaseYear = 1980;
        }
        else
        {
            releaseYear = reY;
        }
        genre = gen;
        if (con < 0.0f || con > 5.0f)
        {
            condition = 0.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            condition = con;
        }
    }

    public void printAudioCD()
    {
        Console.Write(cdTitle + ", " + releaseYear + "\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < artists.Count; i++)
        {
            if (artists[i] != "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Artist (#" + (i + 1) + "): " + artists[i]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Genre: " + genre);
        Console.WriteLine("Condition: " + condition);
    }
}
```

and `Main` method would look like this:

```
// variables
string uI, cdtitle, genre;
int size = 0, releaseYear, choice, arrInd;
List<string> artistArray = new List<string>();
float condition;

Console.Write("How many CDs do you have lying around your car? ");
uI = Console.ReadLine();
size = Convert.ToInt32(uI);

AudioCD[] cd1 = new AudioCD[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CD #" + (i + 1));
    Console.Write("*Enter Title: ");
    uI = Console.ReadLine();
    cdtitle = uI;

    Console.WriteLine("*Enter Artists (type -1 when finished):");
    int j = 0;
    do
    {
        uI = Console.ReadLine();
        if (uI != "-1")
            artistArray[j] = uI;
        j++;

    } while (uI != "-1");

    Console.Write("*Enter Genre: ");
    uI = Console.ReadLine();
    genre = uI;

    Console.Write("*Enter Release Year: ");
    uI = Console.ReadLine();
    releaseYear = Convert.ToInt32(uI);

    Console.Write("*Enter Condition: ");
    uI = Console.ReadLine();
    condition = float.Parse(uI);

    Console.Write("\n");

    // switch to select which class of cd to put information in
    cd1[i] = new AudioCD(cdtitle, artistArray, releaseYear, genre, condition);

    artistArray.Clear();
}

bool isPlaying = true;

while (isPlaying)
{
    Console.Write("\n");
    Console.WriteLine("[Main Menu]");
    Console.WriteLine("1) Album Info");
    Console.WriteLine("2) Find a CD");
    Console.WriteLine("3) Find an artist");
    Console.WriteLine("4) Log off");
    Console.Write("Choice: ");
    uI = Console.ReadLine();
    choice = Convert.ToInt32(uI);

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            {
                Console.Write("\nWhich CD do you want? ");
                uI = Console.ReadLine();
                arrInd = Convert.ToInt32(uI);

                if (arrInd >= 1 || arrInd <= size)
                {
                    Console.Write(arrInd + ". ");
                    cd1[(arrInd - 1)].printAudioCD();
                }

                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                break;
            }
        case 4:
            {
                isPlaying = false;
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                break;
            }
    }
}
```